# How to use groupby function with count(), with the condition only count if i>Num

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
print (df)
     Model  Brand   Type  Jan  Feb  Mar  April  May
0     C310   Benz    Car   10    8   13     29    0
1     C320   Benz    Car   15   11   16      0    7
2    Focus   Ford    Car   10    0    5     20    8
3     F150  Focus  Truck    5    0    5      0    2
4  Ram1500  Dodge  Truck    2    2    7      0    1
5  Caravan  Dodge    Van   20    8   13      5    0
6  Charger  Dodge    Car   17    0    5     10   15
```

I would like to group a data by two columns and count if values in other columns are greater than Num, where Num can be any integer value.

For instance,

```
df.groupby(['Type','Brand']).count()
```

but I would like to only count if the value is greater than Num.

Your assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to add your dataframe data in your question. It's inconvenient to follow a link.

Comment: Very Welcome to the SO , please paste the dataFrame and desired output to get best of the answers for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for replace  values to `NaN`s, because [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) exclude them:

```
Num = 10
cols = df.columns.difference(['Type','Brand', 'Model'])
df[cols] = np.where(df[cols] > Num, df[cols], np.nan)
df = df.groupby(['Type','Brand'])[cols].count() 

print (df)
             April  Feb  Jan  Mar  May
Type  Brand                           
Car   Benz       1    1    1    2    0
      Dodge      0    0    1    0    1
      Ford       1    0    0    0    0
Truck Dodge      0    0    0    0    0
      Focus      0    0    0    0    0
Van   Dodge      0    0    1    1    0
```

Comment: Brilliant!!!! Thank you very much for this jezrael. Thank you all for your contribution as well.

Comment: Ok, just did it. Thanks again